# Regex Conditional validation

Tags: regex

I have a input field, and I want to create a regex that only receive input value from 0.00 to 100.00(include both). I have created a regex check:

```
^1?\d{0,2}(\.\d{1,2})?$
```

But with this one, it not only accept values from 0.00 to 100.00 but also accept the input from 100.01 to 199.99.

How can I set a condition that if there are three digital before the dot, it can be only 100 and the decimals part is 00 or 0 only if having decimals?

So 100.00, 100.0 or 100 are the only accept for the values over 99.99 and the input between 100.01 to 199.99 is not pass.

Here are some passed input:

```
100
100.00
100.0
3
0
0.00
5.2
8.21
37.23
```

Here are some not passed:

```
40.323
100.50
101.50
199.99
40.
100.
```

Comment: this one cannot pass value from 0.00 to 99.99

Comment: @Moon Could you list out more of your requirements? Such as how many digits before the dot and after at least and at most.

Comment: There was a typo. Should be `^(?=.)(100(\.0{1,2})?|\d{1,2}(\.\d{1,2})?)$`. See [tests](https://regex101.com/r/NXUZeJ/1).

Comment: Did any of the posted solutions work out?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
^((?:100(?:\.00?)?)|(?:\d\d?(?:\.\d\d?)?))$
```

It matches:

- x
- x.x
- x.xx
- xx
- xx.x
- xx.xx
- 100
- 100.0
- 100.00

You can get the match via directly match or with the first capturing group :)

P.S. BTW, **@Ouroborus's solution** (in comments) also works, and his solution unexpectedly having the exact same length as mine lol:

> `^(?=.)(100(\.0{1,2})?|\d{1,2}(\.\d{1,2})?)$`

Comment: I've added a wider regex, it shall now meet the needs if so :)

Comment: `100.` should be invalid, only allow `100`, `100.0`, `100.00`.

Comment: okok, now see if it 100% meet your requirements ;)

Comment: Why bother with the capture groups?

Comment: Yea I over considered.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
^(100(\.00?)?|\d\d?)(\.\d\d?)?$
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/wnj3XvrzSDfPe8).

Regex:

- `^` = start
- `(100|\d\d?)` =  literal `100` or 1 or 2 digits
- `(\.\d\d?)?` = dot then 1 or 2 digits, all optional
- `$` = end

Comment: This is allowing 100.01 - 100.99

Comment: @Henryc17 good point. Fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can match 0 - 99 with 1 or 2 optional decimals or 100 with optional `.0` or `.00`

```
^(?:\d\d?(?:\.\d\d?)?|100(?:\.00?)?)$
```

The pattern in parts:

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\d\d?` Match 1-2 digits
  - `(?:\.\d\d?)?` Optionally match `.` and 1-2 digits
  - `|` or
  - `100(?:\.00?)?` Match 100 or 100.0 or 100.00
- `)` Close non capture group
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wasJjk/1)

Comment: `100.0` can not pass.

Comment: @Moon I have update the answer.